# Access Hide Windows, but form in window's taskbar

Tags: ms-access, vba

like the title said, i would like to hide access's windows application but see the item of form in my windows's taskbar.

I already find to hide the access windows with this API:

```
Const SW_HIDE = 0
Const SW_NORMAL = 1

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal FHCmdShow As Long) As Long
```

And: `ShowWindow Application.hWndAccessApp, 0`  for hiding the windows.

And i find this for the item in taskbar:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
 ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
 ByVal nIndex As Long, _
 ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
 ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
 ByVal X As Long, _
 ByVal Y As Long, _
 ByVal cx As Long, _
 ByVal cy As Long, _
 ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Public Sub AppTasklist(frmHwnd)
Dim WStyle  As Long
Dim Result  As Long

WStyle = GetWindowLong(frmHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)

WStyle = WStyle Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW

Result = SetWindowPos(frmHwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                      SWP_NOMOVE Or _
                      SWP_NOSIZE Or _
                      SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
                      SWP_HIDEWINDOW)

Result = SetWindowLong(frmHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WStyle)
Debug.Print Result

Result = SetWindowPos(frmHwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                      SWP_NOMOVE Or _
                      SWP_NOSIZE Or _
                      SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
                      SWP_SHOWWINDOW)


End Sub
```

But i don't know how to make this work, i've tried fews things but nothing work.
Anyone have already use it or can help me?

Comment: What do you mean with _see the item of form in my windows's taskbar._?

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble to understand what you are trying to achieve. **1. You want to hide the Windows Access Application from the windows task bar. 2. You want to bring the Access Application back by pressing your Windows Application Form?**

Comment: No, i already hide the Windows Access Application but i would like to have item for my form (who is modal and pop-up to yes) in my windows task bar, because when the Windows Access Application is hide we see nothing in windows task bar. Am I clear? :)

Comment: I find the code on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594043/access-application-hidden-application-window-with-form-taskbar-icon    it is what i want but it's doesn't work or i don't know how to make it work (more probably)

Comment: Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Comment: 2010 and 2013 too

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. There was an Access application option in earlier versions to display forms as separate items on the Windows taskbar, but it was removed starting, I think, with the 2010 version.

Comment: da**it, the code above apparently works but I can not make it work!

Comment: Where is the procedure that declares and sets frmHwnd?